# How to check if current admin page is Gutenberg editor?

Tags: block-editor

Previously I could use `is_gutenberg_page()`, but this function seems to be gone after 5.0 release.

Any tips on how to check if current admin page is gutenberg editor?

Comment: please try this code but i am not confirm

Comment: global $current_screen;
$current_screen = get_current_screen();
if ( ( method_exists($current_screen, 'is_block_editor') && $current_screen->is_block_editor() )
  || ( function_exists('is_gutenberg_page')) && is_gutenberg_page() ) ) {
    // DO SOMETHING
}

Answer (score 3):

In 5.0 new function was introduced ([docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_screen/is_block_editor/)):

```
WP_Screen::is_block_editor( bool $set = null )
```

which sets or returns whether the block editor is loading on the current screen.

So you can do that check using this code:

```
global $current_screen;
$current_screen = get_current_screen();
if ( method_exists($current_screen, 'is_block_editor') && $current_screen->is_block_editor() ) {
    // DO SOMETHING
}
```

You can also add to this condition

```
|| ( function_exists('is_gutenberg_page')) && is_gutenberg_page() )
```

to be compatible with older versions.